# What is the scope of PHARs

Tags: php, phar

I am building a web application that will accept 3rd party code to be deployed. I was wondering (and a few searches in Google didn't show anything).

On what scope does a PHAR archive run? Does it have application access or it is contained inside the scope of the archive?

As an explaining example:
<s>If I have in **Application** a config file (for simplicity's sake) will the **PHAR** be able to reach it?</s>

Is there a way to share objects between PHAR and the Application code? Like using a singleton or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special restrictions of files in phars, compared to "normal" files on the harddisk.

You can include and access files outside the phar without problems.

---

Your application will behave as before as long as you have the include path/autoloader setup correctly.

Comment: I had further research and saw that I can include files that are outside the PHAR if I play nice and use full paths (That is why I striked the config). But what about calling a singleton of an active DB class (for example)? It will work as intended or I need to DI it